# Specific UI Testing in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, xcode-ui-testing

I am new to UI Testing in Xcode 7, and I find it very difficult to determinate how can I test multiple details about my app. I have been able to test the basic things, such as different labels exist, and their values are changed when I tap the corresponding buttons.

However, I have no idea how can I test that the color of these labels changes to the one desired, or that a new screen is presented modally when I tap a button. After searching in Google and Stackoverflow I have found nothing but the basic tutorials that let me test what I have already accomplished. How should I proceed to expand my tests and make them actually useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some limitations.  I don't believe testing color (or fonts for example) is possible... yet.  However you can definitely test the navigation from screen to screen...

`XCTAssertTrue(app.navigationBars["ViewControllerTitle"].exists)`

Of course, it all depends on how your screen works.  In the example, we're assuming there is a disabled navigation bar label.  You just have to find something visual (text) on the screen that uniquely identifies it.  It does take some getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the specifics for testing for color are not yet possible.  However, you might want to consider Unit Tests for that.  You can test GUI components for color in those.  That's where the line between Unit and UI Testing can get a bit blurry.  But, if you need to test for color, that is one way to do it.